# choco list <package> omits results

Tags: chocolatey

On my machine at home, `choco list <package>` works fine. On my machine at work, it does not.

Behavior on machine at work:

Fine:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> choco list --exact --all maven
Chocolatey v0.10.3
maven 3.3.9.1 ...
maven 3.3.3 ...
...
9 packages found.
```

Fine:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> choco list --exact maven
Chocolatey v0.10.3
maven 3.3.9.1 ...
1 packages found.
```

Fine:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> choco list --all maven
Chocolatey v0.10.3
biicode 2.8 ...
...
maven 3.3.9.1 ...
maven 3.3.3 ...
...
57 packages found.
```

Not fine:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> choco list maven
Chocolatey v0.10.3
0 packages found.
```

I would expect at least one package, namely `maven 3.3.9.1`.

I do not have that problem with all packages. E.g.:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> choco list notepadplusplus
Chocolatey v0.10.3
jivkok.dev1 1.1.0.8
notepadplusplus 7.3.2 ...
...
5 packages found.
```

- Windows 7 SP1 64 Bit
- .NET Framework 4.6.1
- Fresh Chocolatey v0.10.3 installation
- Chocolatey run in Powershell 5.0 as administrator

Comment: Unsure what you may be running into. It's likely that there is something wonky going on - keep in mind you are using the community package repository which is a service that is under a bit of load constantly. It has 15M+ requests per day and most of the time it returns results just fine. Seldomly it caches something incorrectly or you hit a load balancer that is rebuilding indexes and it wasn't able to answer your request in time before the client timed out.

Comment: Thanks. You are probably right. Just tried it again and it seems to be fine now.